# Using the Google Actions console gives me an error, even if I didn't change anything in the sample project

Tags: google-cloud-platform, actions-on-google, google-developers-console, google-assistant, actions-builder

I'm trying to make a custom google action using the [Google Actions console](https://console.actions.google.com/). So far I've had a pretty rough time, given that all the tutorials I found are outdated(-2020). What I did was start with a sample Hello World project:
[image: Starting with a hello world project]

And then go straight to the test tab (I did this because I thought I was doing something wrong).
Every time I try to test I get the error message "Cloud function deployment failed":

[image: Getting the error]

I tried looking around in the official documentation, but I couldn't find anything that helped.

Answer (score 2):

First - it is important that you understand that any Conversational Actions created using the Actions console [will be shut down](https://developers.google.com/assistant/ca-sunset) starting June 13th, 2023.

I think the problem in your case is that the Hello World uses the Inline Cloud Functions Editor to hold the code. You can see this if you go to the Develop tab along the top and then the Webhook navigation on the left.

As the banner says there, in order to deploy this function, you need to associate the project with a billing account in the Google Cloud console. Without this billing account, it won't be able to deploy the function, and you'll get that vague error.

[image: Cloud Functions editor]